# How do I make sure the driver for a TP-LINK tl-wn727n is loaded on boot?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb

Last week I bought this adpator and had trouble getting it to work. [How do I get a  TP-Link TN-WN727N usb wireless stick working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134170/new-tp-link-tn-wn727n-usb-wireless-stick-how-do-i-get-it-working) but thanks to some help got it running.

However the main issue now is that while the device works with the `sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb`, I'm having to input it every time I reboot the system.  Is there anything I can do to make this work automatically after a reboot.

Comment: I used the command 'sudo gedit /etc/modules' and add rt2800usb under the last item in the list.  Saved and rebooted.  Wireless started up automatically.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the last post here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1902715

> ```
> sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
> ```
>
> and the wireless worked immediately.
>
> I then removed the blacklisted drivers (which I added earlier) from
>   `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
>
> Next I added `rt2800usb` to `/etc/modules`. Rebooted and my wireless
>   starts up automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.