# SMCWUSBS-N3 Ralink RT3070 disconnected wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb, ralink

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64bits, and this wireless pen to connect to the internet.

I've tried to update the driver from RT2870 to RT3070, downloading the latest linux drivers from SMC website.

After that, my wireless networks disappeared and I can't connect.

Here's the output of `lsusb` when pen connected:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 083a:a701 Accton Technology Corp. SMCWUSBS-N3 EZ Connect N Wireless Adapter [Ralink RT3070]
```

The output of `nmcli nm`:

```
RUNNING STATE        WIFI-HARWARE WIFI    WWAN-HARDWARE WWAN

running disconnected enabled      enabled enabled       disabled
```

What's happenning?

Thanks for your help!

Tiago

Comment: Are you certain the device ID isn't 083a:a701? If so, please edit your question. What about the default rt2800usb was not working as expected?

Comment: thanks chili555, in fact the id was wrong. Just edited the question. The original driver was always dropping the connection, so I went to the website to download the latest drivers.

Comment: help would be very appreciated...at least to rollback to the old driver...otherwise I'll have to make a clean ubuntu install...thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem based on [How do I make sure the driver for a TP-LINK tl-wn727n is loaded on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136083/how-do-i-make-sure-the-driver-for-a-tp-link-tl-wn727n-is-loaded-on-boot)

After I've made what chili555 told, I've notice that the rt2800usb wasn't loading at boot, so I had to assure that the module was loaded at boot:

```
sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

I already had removed the blacklisted drivers from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Next I added rt2800usb to /etc/modules:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Rebooted and my wireless starts up automatically.

Note: when making **lsusb** my info remais the same:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 083a:a701 Accton Technology Corp. SMCWUSBS-N3 EZ Connect N Wireless Adapter [Ralink RT3070]
```

Worked like a charm! :) Thanks chili555!

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised you got the driver from SMC to compile at all. Let's try to uninstall it. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Release2010
```

...or wherever you downloaded and extracted the file if not Downloads. Press Tab and let the remainder of the long filename fill in; press Enter.

```
cd Drivers/Linux
```

I assume you extracted the RT3070 tar file within.

```
cd 2009
```

Press Tab and let the remainder of the long filename fill in; press Enter. Now, finally, we uninstall:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

If the original 'make' failed, then there is actually no need to uninstall.

Did you blacklist the native driver?

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

If you do not have gedit, use leafpad, kate, nano or any text editor. If you have blacklisted rt2800usb, remove that line. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot and tell us your symptoms. We'll troubleshoot from there.

Comment: this is the output of make uninstall, I also removed the rt2800usb from blacklist.conf and the output of lsusb and nmcli nm remains the same.

Comment: ~/drivers/SMC/2009_0525_RT3070$ sudo make uninstall  
*make -C /home/posto-11/drivers/SMC/2009_0525_RT3070/os/linux -f Makefile.6 uninstall*
_make[1]: Entering directory `/home/posto-11/drivers/SMC/2009_0525_RT3070/os/linux'_
*rm -rf /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt3070sta.ko_
*/sbin/depmod -a 3.13.0-27-generic*
_make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/posto-11/drivers/SMC/2009_0525_RT3070/os/linux'_

Comment: sorry, the unformated comment above

Comment: Did rt2800usb load? lsmod Is there any informative message? dmesg   | grep rt2 and also: rfkill list all Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find any message related to rt2800usb, when making lsmod, probably it didn't boot. made dmesg | grep rt2 and rfkill list all. Rebooted the computer and still remains the same.thanks for your patiente! ;)

Comment: I've made make menuconfig and under ralink driver support all rt2800usb are marked with [*]