# How to get ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter running on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ralink

I've got issues getting ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter to run ob an Ubuntu 12.04 box. I've downloaded latest sources from http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/dl.php and compiled them with activated support for:

```
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

make and make install worked without any issues.

Also I added to blacklisted list:

```
blacklist rt2800usb
blacklist rt2870sta
```

When inserting the device I'm getting

```
[ 1625.120102] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[ 1625.232103] 
[ 1625.232106] 
[ 1625.232107] === pAd = ffffc900228ea000, size = 598360 ===
[ 1625.232109] 
[ 1625.232241] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
[ 1625.232419] Efuse Size=0x2d [2d0-2fc] 
[ 1625.232776] NVM is EFUSE
[ 1625.249500] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ra0: link is not ready
```

Syslog is extending this a bit:

```
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.120102] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232103] 
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232106] 
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232107] === pAd = ffffc900228ea000, size = 598360 ===
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232109] 
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232241] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232419] Efuse Size=0x2d [2d0-2fc] 
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.232776] NVM is EFUSE
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/net/ra0, iface: ra0)
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/net/ra0, iface: ra0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-10) Operation not supported
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): driver does not support SSID scans (scan_capa 0x00).
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): using WEXT for WiFi device control
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <error> [1384878423.166788] [nm-device-wifi.c:2591] real_update_permanent_hw_address(): (ra0): unable to read permanent MAC address (error 0)
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'usb' ifindex: 7)
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): now managed
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): bringing up device.
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <info> (ra0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <warn> (ra0): error 100 getting card mode
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <error> [1384878423.168059] [wifi-utils-wext.c:155] wifi_wext_set_mode(): (ra0): error setting mode 2
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa kernel: [ 1625.249500] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ra0: link is not ready
Nov 19 17:27:03 betschwa NetworkManager[1092]: <warn> (ra0): error 100 getting card mode
```

What else am I missing? Is there maybe any deb for Ubuntu anywhere available?

Comment: Does this answer help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/134176