# Ubuntu 14.04 - TP-Link TL-WN727N

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter

I just bought a TP-Link TL-WN727N wireless USB adapter. I plugged it into my machine and booted, but nothing seemed to happen. I ran lsusb and there she was

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

From this thread [How do I get a  TP-Link TN-WN727N usb wireless stick working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134170/how-do-i-get-a-tp-link-tn-wn727n-usb-wireless-stick-working) I saw I should try running (note the command is now edited for my device id, 148f 7601)

```
echo 'install rt2800usb modprobe --ignore-install rt2800usb ; /bin/echo "148f 7601"      > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/new_id' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf
sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

Nothing seemed to happen and I still don't see any wireless networks detected under the network manager menu. iwconfig just prints

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check here: http://superuser.com/questions/774554/linux-unable-to-get-usb-wifi-drivers-to-work-or-compile In summary; "...it appears no one has managed to make it compile successfully on a recent kernel. I have seen reports for 3.12 to 3.15."

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I should have researched the drivers more instead of rushing out to buy something...

Comment: There are several questions here and on ubuntuforums.org about supported devices to help you along.

Comment: Look carefully, as you mentioned in title, you need driver for TL-WN727N, not TN-WN727N! Try [this answer.](http://askubuntu.com/a/578017/374167)

Answer (score 2):

Update for anyone who needs it:

The wireless module did not start after rebooting so I ran
sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb

and the wireless worked immediately.

I then removed the blacklisted drivers (which I added earlier) from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Next I added rt2800usb to /etc/modules. Rebooted and my wireless starts up automatically.

Sorted

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 14.04 and do you get the same output from lsusb as me (specifically the ID 148f:7601 bit)? If so great! Looks like someone fixed it