# Problem with driver for TP-LINK TL-WN727N on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, usb

I just brought a TP-Link WN727N wireless adapter to work on ubuntu since my default wifi has issues. My system is HP-ab030tx.
lsusb produces the following result :

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.

So the system recognizes the usb. I have tried following solutions till now.

1. chili555's first answer from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577941/installing-the-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn727n-on-ubuntu-14-04)
2. Also tried to install rt2800usb using instructions from 
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Tenda_W311M

The problem now is as soon as i plug in the device the light in the device brightens up and the system freezes or undergoes a kernel panick. 
Tried the same thing on ubuntu 15.10 with the same result.
I cannot try new coomands with the usb on now since it freezes everytime. 
Right now i am on ubuntu 14.04.3 which also has the same problem.
I have been on this over a week. Please suggest me a solution.
PS : Please let me know if anyone wants to know anything about any commands from my OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is covered by default in Ubuntu 15.10. You are probably only missing the firmware. Download and install the firmware with:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601
cd mt7601/src/mcu/bin
sudo cp MT7601.bin /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

Insert the device and it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked for 5-10 mins and then kernel panicked again. Does it have anything to do with built in wifi? I switched off the built in wireless by 'sudo ifconfig wlo1 down'

Comment: I suggest we blacklist the driver for the internal device. Please post: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: Okay. So the output of the command is : 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804c]

Comment: I then blacklisted the driver rtl8723be in blacklist.conf file but still the laptop froze like before after 10 min.

Comment: Did you reboot after the blacklist? Any clues in `/var/log/syslog`? Make a note of the time of the freeze and after a reboot, check the log for what happened just before and at that time. Paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Yes i did reboot after blacklisting. I inserted the device at 11:03:06 and the freeze took place at 11:07 . The link for the log file is http://paste.ubuntu.com/13436601/

Comment: I see this that is alarming: "WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-AxjFAn/linux-4.2.0/kernel/softirq.c:150 __local_bh_enable_ip+0x6c/0x90()" Softirq is not related to wireless. I suggest you Google it or ask a separate question. Then see my next comment.

Comment: I also see this: " WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:212: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.DatabaseError: SQL error: 5, database is locked" It may be the subject of a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zeitgeist/+bug/1486445 It appears to be related to networking, but not wireless, per se. Again, I'd Google it and ask a new question. Your wireless appears to connect and operate correctly.

Comment: Alright i will look it up. Thanks a lot for the help. And one last thing, is there a possibility that the device might work on any other linux distro like linux mint or fedora maybe? Thanks again.