# lenovo no inbuilt wifi how to connect to wifi using adapter

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, system-installation

I am using lenovo 3000 g 430 laptop which does not have built in wifi I bought a tplink TL w572n adapter i can install its drivers on windows easily but coming to ubuntu it doesnt get like that please help  me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

It could just be that it simply doesn't have drivers for Ubuntu. Try and google "tplink TL w572 drivers linux" and see what comes up. If nothing relevant comes up, then the adapter is sadly not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04, driver mt7601u is already included in 4.X version of kernel.

However, if you prefer to use Ubuntu 14.04 follow this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577941/installing-the-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn727n-on-ubuntu-14-04).